# ¿Cómo soluciono el error 424 de depuración de Visual Basic?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

La idea de este código es poder realizar un registro en una tabla con los datos que se muesran en el formulario. Tomando en cuenta que los datos a introducir son únicamente: Nombre del activo, precio y año.
Al hacer clic en pre cacular, Depreciación mensual y Revaluación deben de llenarse solos.
Posterior a ello, al dar clic en Aceptar, el formulario inserta el registro enla tabla.

Sin embargo, al hacer clic en el botón de "Pre calular", me arroja el código de error de compilación 424 "Falta un objeto".

Adjunto código y copia del archivo en un enlace de Mega [[Archivo](https://mega.nz/file/aYxCAZZY#8dxyGhpzXnIbQ4vltdHT7q5LzVrz9PsqizZeQOeujwU)][1](https://mega.nz/file/aYxCAZZY#8dxyGhpzXnIbQ4vltdHT7q5LzVrz9PsqizZeQOeujwU):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` no es VBA, es VB.NET. Son dos lenguajes diferentes con una sintaxis parecida. Las funciones de conversión en VBA son https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero deberías Validar que los valores ingresados sean numericos, ya que puedes poner por error un texto y te genera un error.
Puedes usar la Funcion CDbl() para convertir los valores de los texbox en Tipo Double.

Te paso la función CommandButton2_Click() que funciona correctamente, puedes modificarla para darle mas inteligencia.

```
Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim A, B As Double

 If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) Then
  A = CDbl(TextBox2.Text) / CDbl(TextBox3.Text) * 60
 Else
  MsgBox ("los campos no son numericos")
  Exit Sub
 End If

 B = Math.Round(A, 2)
 TextBox4 = B
 TextBox5 = Val(TextBox2) * 0.25
End Sub
```